# Cannot connect to MariaDB after upgrade from MySQL

Tags: c#, mariadb, connector-net

I had MySQL5.7 on my Windows machine. I have installed MariaDB 10.7 and uninstalled MySQL.

I restored the MySQL dump file in MariaDB. I can connect to MariaDB now using MySQL Workbench and query the DB correctly.

However when I try to connect to the DB using C# code I get the following exception:

> Versions of MySQL prior to 5.6 are not currently supported

and this is the inner exception:

> Versions of MySQL prior to 5.6 are not currently supported

Comment: Renew your connector.

Comment: And remember: mariadb is not mysql....

Comment: @Shadow: I really don't understand how is this helpful?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini MariaDB already rolled out its own drivers. If you replace mysql with mariadb, you should be using mariadb drivers, not mysql, to guarantee that the drivers work with mariadb. Don't treat the two products as same.

Comment: Driver, connector, same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a higher version of the MySQL connector library.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html